# What happens when Apache Pig loads/stores a relation?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm learning about Apache Pig. And I'm also new to Hadoop. So could anyone please tell me what happens when Pig LOAD/STORE a relation? Better in detail, such as what functions will it invoke and in which order?

That will do a great help to me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not think about LOAD/STORE isolated.

When you issue series of pig commands, it will build execution plan based up on Map Reduce APIs using Java. It uses lazy evaluation and the map reduce job will be submitted once DUMP or STORE command is encountered.

Here is the sample script:

```
department_rows = LOAD '/apps/hive/warehouse/retail_ods.db/departments' ;
department_group = GROUP department_rows ALL;
department_count = FOREACH department_group GENERATE COUNT_STAR(department_rows) as ct;
DUMP department_count;
```

Above query try to get number of records in the table.

> LOAD command will be reading data from HDFS location using map reduce api. The data will be represented as BAG in Pig terminology. BAG is assigned to department_rows
>   Next 2 statements will be converted into map reduce logic to get the count
>   DUMP will invoke the logic to return the final output in standard output.

At any step you can issue EXPLAIN  (eg: EXPLAIN department_count) to get the explain plan using map and reduce. If you are new to Hadoop, it will be tough to understand it. You need to start from basics of HDFS, map reduce and then get into Pig.